# How to post images and pictures?

Tags: support, images

I have some DIY questions (mostly electrical with wiring and grounds and stuff) and I need to show pictures (cannot describe it adequately). I read up on how to show images but it is all with LINKS and I am a little confused.

So I took some pictures with my phone and now I want to add them to a post. Can someone help me out with a step-by-step?

Comment: What type of phone are you using (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Symbian, something else). Are you using the Stack Exchange app or the mobile website? Have you seen: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/989/how-do-i-add-pictures-to-a-question-from-my-phone and http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer

Comment: Using my windows PC for posting ... I take a pic with my android 4.4.2 phone, copy it to my PC ... and then ... not sure how to post it

Comment: Once the photos are on your PC, http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer should give you all the information that you need. Note that photos can be a maximum of 2MBytes in size, so if your phone takes photos that are bigger than that, you'll have to resize or crop them in photo editing software.